# CakePHP wont work with Ajax jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3, cakephp-2.1

I'm very desperate about this situation because I've spent over 3 days trying to find my mistake in this code.

My application should retrieve some clients geo coordinates from database via my controller and it should return a JSON with the coordinates to be plot in the view as markers on a Google Map div.

But when I run the application nothing happen, only my form loads, but the Google Map does not show, consequently the markers doesn't as well.

This is my code: I have a CakePHP controller method which returns a JSON response just fine(I've checked in Chrome Console).

Code:

```
    class ClientsController extends AppController {

          public $helpers = array('Js'=>array('Jquery'), 'GoogleMap', 'Html', 'Form');
          public $components = array('RequestHandler');


          public function loadJsonMarkers() {
              $conditions = array(
                                   'not' => array('Client.geoloc' => null),
                                   'geoloc !=' => '(-1,-1)'
                                  );

             if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
                $clients = $this->Client->find('all', array(
                                                  'conditions' => $conditions,
                                                  'fields' => array('Client.geoloc'),
                                                  'recursive' => -1
                                               ));

              $this->header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8');
              return new CakeResponse(array('type'=> 'json', 'body' => json_encode(array('clients' => $clients))));

           }
      }
```

Then I have the webpage with the Ajax Request:

```
         function mapCaller(sentData)
         {

            $.ajax({
                       url: 'clients/loadJsonMarkers',
                       accepts: 'json',
                       type: 'POST',
                       data: sentData,
                       dataType: 'json',
                       error: function(xhr,status,err){
                             alert("DEBUG: status"+status+" \nError:"+err);
                       },  
                       success: function(transport){   

                             var markers = new Array();

                             for(var i in transport.clients){
                                 var latlng = transport.clients[i].Client.geoloc.replace("(", "");
                                 latlng = latlng.replace(")", "");
                                 latlng = latlng.split(',');

                                 markers.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlng[0]),parseFloat(latlng[1])));
                             }

                             plotMap(markers);

                             $('#map-loading').fadeOut('slow');

                       },
                       complete: function(){
                             console.log(data);
                             console.log(sentData);
                       }
         });   

         function plotMap(markers)
         {   
            var mapOptions = { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

             var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

             var markersCondensed = new Array(); 
             var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 

             $.each
             (markers,
             function(key, value){   
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: value });
                  markersCondensed.push(marker);

                  bounds.extend(value);
              }
              );

              var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50}; 
              var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersCondensed, mcOptions);

              if (markers.length > 0)
                  map.fitBounds(bounds); 
              else
                  $('#map-no-results').fadeIn('slow');
          }
```

And in my view: index.ctp
               
            Html->image("open-search.png", array('id'=>'open-search', 'class'=>'divlink')); ?>
            Html->link(
                    $this->Html->image("clear-search.png", array('class'=>'divlink')),
                    "#maps", array('escape'=>false)) ?>

```
    <div id="search-box">
        <?= $this->Html->image("hide-search.png",array('id'=>'close-search', 'class'=>'divlink')); ?>

        <div class="form">
            <?= $this->Form->create('User',array('action'=>'filter')); ?>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Vendas</legend>
                <fieldset class="sub-fieldset">  <?php //TODO define style for ?>
                    <legend class="sub-legenda">Data da venda</legend>
                    <?= $this->Form->input('Sale.0.sale_date_min', array('label'=>'A partir do dia:', 'type'=>'date')); ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->input('Sale.0.sale_date_max', array('label'=>'Até o dia', 'type'=>'date'));  ?>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="sub-fieldset">
                    <legend class="sub-legenda">Total da venda</legend>
                    <?= $this->Form->input('Sale.0.sale_total_min', array('label' => 'Valor mínimo', 'class' => 'money')); ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->input('Sale.0.sale_total_max', array('label' => 'Valor máximo', 'class' => 'money')); ?>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Clientes</legend>
                <?= $this->Form->label('Client.sex', 'Sexo:'); ?>
                <?= $this->Form->checkbox('Client.sex', array('value'=> 'm')); ?>
                <?= $this->Form->checkbox('Client.sex', array('value'=> 'f')); ?>

                <fieldset class="sub-fieldset">
                    <legend class="sub-legenda">Faixa etária</legend>
                    <?= $this->Form->input('Client.age_min', array('label' => 'Idade mínima')); ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->input('Client.age_max', array('label' => 'Idade máxima')); ?>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="sub-fieldset">
                    <legend class="sub-legenda">Renda</legend>
                    <?= $this->Form->input('Client.income_min', array('label' => 'Renda mínima', 'class' => 'money')); ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->input('Client.income_max', array('label' => 'Renda máxima', 'class' => 'money')); ?>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div id="map-loading" class="notice-box">
        <p><?= $this->Html->image("ajax-loading.gif"); ?>Carregando o mapa...</p>
    </div>


    <div id="map-no-results" class="notice-box">
        <p><a href="maps">SEM RESULTADOS</a></p>
    </div>
```

This should work fine since I always got a jqXHR.readystate = 4 and a SERVER STATE = 200, but my page does not load the map.

Some screenshots of my application:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67445902/server_status_response.png

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67445902/loaded_app.png

After a long time debbuging it I think it is a problem with the Ajax callback(success), but I can't affirm certainly about it.

Any help about It would be very nice.

Note: Sorry if I got something wrong in my English. I'm a brazilian and I know just a little bit of English.

## UPDATE

I've achieved to got this thing working. I had to create a new template with nothing inside the body but,

```
               <? echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
```

I really dont't know why but, it worked. If someone knows why or at least have a clue. Please tell me.

Comment: Pedro, if you address code indentation and curly brace balance, then people will have a fighting chance of seeing what might be going on.

Comment: What error are you receiving in the console? You should be able to confirm/deny if it's an ajax issue.

Comment: This is the point, I'm not receiving any errors from console. Here is a snapshot of console: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67445902/no_errors.png

Comment: Just to update, I've tried with the AJAX request from Prototype Library, but I got the same behavior.

Comment: Hi @PedroTanaka, I know it's been some time, but could you answer your own question an accept the answer? If the blank templated worked, maybe the Gmaps js was overlapping with some of your js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that all of this was happening because of an css error, when I set the height of map-canvas div the map shown up.

The css code to map-canvas and other elements are:

```
          #map_canvas label{width:auto; display:inline; height: 900px; /*Your height here*/}
          #map_canvas img{max-width:none}
          .gmaps label{width:auto; display:inline}
          .gmaps img{max-width:none}
```

And set a fixed value to the parent div of map-canvas or to map-canvas, like:

```
         <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```