# Cakephp how to make ajax request with jsHelper

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I want to rewrite this jQuery Ajax Request which is not working well with cakePHP with a code block in my cakePHP view using JsHelper. 
So far, I've setup everything( included the helper in my controller, written the buffer in my Layout, included my library(jQuery) ), but I dont know how to rewrite this:

```
         $.ajax
            ({
                url: 'clients/loadJsonMarkers',
                accepts: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                data: postData,
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(xhr,status,err){
                    alert("DEBUG: status"+status+" \nError:"+err);
                },  
                success: function(transport)
                {   

                    var markers = new Array();

                    for(var i in transport.clients)
                    {
                        var latlng = transport.clients[i].Client.geoloc.replace("(", "");
                        latlng = latlng.replace(")", "");
                        latlng = latlng.split(',');

                        //console.debug(latlng);
                        markers.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlng[0]),parseFloat(latlng[1])));
                    }

                    loadMap(markers);

                }
            });
```

What I've achieved to write so far was this:

```
    $this->Js->get('document');
    $this->Js->event('load',
            $this->Js->request(
                array('action' => 'loadJsonMarkers'),
                array('assync'=>TRUE, 'type'=>'json', 'method'=>'POST', 'data'=>$_POST)
                ),
            array('success'=>$this->Html->scriptBlock("
                    function(transport)
                    {   
                        var markers = new Array();

                        for(var i in transport.clients)
                        {
                            var latlng = transport.clients[i].Client.geoloc.replace('(', '');
                            latlng = latlng.replace('(', '');
                            latlng = latlng.split(',');

                            //console.debug(latlng);
                            markers.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlng[0]),parseFloat(latlng[1])));
                        }

                        loadMap(markers);

                    }"
            ))
    );
```

But I feel like something is missing and I don't know if I should use this selector(document).

Comment: Why not write it as regular JS since you already have it? It is [likely it will be removed](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/cakephp-core/UaXqk_rTdxE/discussion) in CakePHP 3.0 anyway.

Comment: Man, I've tried to. I swear, this was a blind shot, a desperate attempt to get this thing working. Here is my first question, where my JS code is not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486895/cakephp-wont-work-with-ajax-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Cake buffers everything and places it in a `$(document).ready()` function, all you should need to do is add it to the buffer.

```
$request = $this->Js->request(
  array('action' => 'loadJsonMarkers'),
  array(
    'async' => true, 
    'type' => 'json', 
    'method' => 'POST', 
    'data' => $_POST,
    'wrapCallbacks' => false,
    'success' => "function(transport) {
      var markers = new Array();

      for(var i in transport.clients) {
        var latlng = transport.clients[i].Client.geoloc.replace('(', '');
        latlng = latlng.replace('(', '');
        latlng = latlng.split(',');

        markers.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlng[0]),parseFloat(latlng[1])));
      }
      loadMap(markers);
    }"
  )  
);
$this->Js->buffer($request);
```

Make sure you're writing the buffer in your layout.

However, since you've already got the pure JS writting you should probably just buffer that, since the JsHelper will [likely be removed in CakePHP 3.0](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/cakephp-core/UaXqk_rTdxE/discussion).

Comment: Man, thanks for your help, but It still doesn't work. The code is executed, I can see in the debug, but nothing happens in the application, not even my map is plotted.

Comment: Man you wouldn't believe, but after 5 days trying to discover what the hell was going on with this code, I got it, it was a problem with my view, I should delete all the content that was inside of <body>, I don't know why, but it is working now.

Comment: Just to let you know, I've found out that I was having a problem with my css and solved my problem with the tips on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548330/zoom-bar-disfigured-in-google-maps-for-rails-gmaps4rails